# cycling images with left and right controls

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I did it with cycleImages function but I've no idea how to complete the another half, which is navigate to the left. Try to click the right button and see the effect.

```js
function cycleImages(){
      var $active = $('#background_cycler .active');
      var $next = ($('#background_cycler .active').next().length > 0) ? $('#background_cycler .active').next() : $('#background_cycler img:first');
      $next.css('z-index',2);//move the next image up the pile
   $active.fadeOut(800,function(){//fade out the top image
   $active.css('z-index',1).show().removeClass('active');//reset the z-index and unhide the image
      $next.css('z-index',3).addClass('active');//make the next image the top one
      });
    }



    $('.rightArrow').click(function(){
    cycleImages();
 })

 $('.leftArrow').click(function(){
    
 })
```

```css
 #background_cycler{padding:0;margin:0;width:100%;top:0;z-index:-1;left:0;position:absolute;}
#background_cycler img{position:absolute;left:0;top:0;width:100%;z-index:1;background-size:cover;}
#background_cycler img.active{z-index:3}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="background_cycler" >
 <img class="active" src="http://placehold.it/300&text=1" alt=""/>
 <img src="http://placehold.it/300&text=2" alt=""   />
 <img src="http://placehold.it/300&text=3" alt=""  />
 <img src="http://placehold.it/300&text=4" alt=""/>  
</div>

<button class="left">left</button>
<button class="rightArrow">right</button>
```

Comment: Your may want to introduce a parameter in your `cycleImages()` to handle the direction.

Answer (score 0):

Apply same logic when you click Left button, pass parameter to `cycleImages` function say `direction`, to determine which button was clicked, as:

```
function cycleImages( direction ){
    var $active = $('#background_cycler .active'),
        $dir; //holds 'right' or 'left' direction
    if( "right" == direction) {
        $dir = ($('#background_cycler .active').next().length > 0) ? $('#background_cycler .active').next() : $('#background_cycler img:first');
    }
    else {
        $dir = ($('#background_cycler .active').prev().length > 0) ?    $('#background_cycler .active').prev() : $('#background_cycler img:last');
    }
    $dir.css('z-index',2);
    $active.fadeOut(800,function(){
        $active.css('z-index',1).show().removeClass('active');
        $dir.css('z-index',3).addClass('active');
    });
}

$('.rightArrow').click(function(){
    cycleImages('right');
})

$('.leftArrow').click(function(){
   cycleImages('left');
})
```

html

```
. . .
<button class="leftArrow">left</button>
<button class="rightArrow">right</button>
```

Demo [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zrcop8f9/)

Answer (score 0):

Try

html

```
<button class="prev">left</button>
<button class="next">right</button>
```

js

```
function cycleImages(idx) {
  var $active = $("#background_cycler .active")
  , $next = $active[idx]().is("*") 
            ? $active[idx]() 
            : idx === "prev" 
              ? $active.siblings().eq($active.index("img") - 1) 
              : $active.siblings().addBack().eq(0);
  $next.css("z-index", 2); 
  $active.fadeOut(800, function() { 
    $active.css("z-index", 1).show().removeClass("active");        
    $next.css("z-index", 3).addClass("active"); 
  });
};

$("button").click(function(e) {
  cycleImages(e.target.className)
});
```

```js
function cycleImages(idx) {
  var $active = $("#background_cycler .active")

  , $next = $active[idx]().is("*") 
            ? $active[idx]() 
            : idx === "prev" 
              ? $active.siblings().eq($active.index("img") - 1) 
              : $active.siblings().addBack().eq(0);

  $next.css("z-index", 2); //move the next image up the pile
  $active.fadeOut(800, function() { //fade out the top image
    $active.css("z-index", 1).show().removeClass('active'); //reset the z-index and unhide the image
    $next.css("z-index", 3).addClass("active"); //make the next image the top one
  });

};

$("button").click(function(e) {
  cycleImages(e.target.className)
});
```

```css
#background_cycler {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
#background_cycler img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  background-size: cover;
}
#background_cycler img.active {
  z-index: 3
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="background_cycler">
  <img class="active" src="http://placehold.it/300&text=1" alt="" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/300&text=2" alt="" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/300&text=3" alt="" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/300&text=4" alt="" />
</div>

<button class="prev">left</button>
<button class="next">right</button>
```